# How to add divider between two Horizontal Scroll Bar in android by programmatically

Tags: android, horizontal-scrolling

I want to add divider between two Horizontal Scroll Bar by programmatically.

Comment: what your xml looks like

Comment: I create all object in dynamic so my xml is nothing importanct

Answer (score 1):

```
ImageView divider = new ImageView(this);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = 
new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
lp.setMargins(left, top, right, bottom);
divider.setLayoutParams(lp);
divider.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
```

Comment: This method is not work for me when i pass HorizontalScrollBar object it give error

Comment: Why use an ImageView when a View is of lighter weight and serves the same purpose?

Answer (score -1):

You can just create a simple View and set its height to 1 or 2 (or whatever your desired thickness of the line is) and the width to whatever you may want that to be (MATCH_PARENT?). You can change the color of it by simple setting this View background (setBackgroundColor). This is the easiest method.

```
`View divider = new View
`divider.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, toolKit.size(1), 0, toolKit.size(1), 0, 0));
        divider.setBackgroundColor(toolKit.getColor(R.color.white_50_per));
```

Comment: The toolkit that I am sure you are still using is not a public class. That is of my own making. That should be enough for you to figure out how to do it and learn what is actually happening instead of just copy pasting.

Comment: Thanks for the downvote because you just wanted something you could copy and paste...

Comment: it's true i don't understand your example but that also true i can't down your vote.